# (VS13) mysqlclient.lib compiles (i think) as Static Multithreaded Debug even if the Runtime Library setting is Multithreaded Debug DLL

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2013, linker

I'm trying to compile the **mysqlclient.lib** library as a Multithreaded Debug DLL. I need it in this configuration to be able to link it to my project. To give some context I will explain what have I done so far:

1. I cloned the MySQL repository: `git clone https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server.git`
2. I created the **MySQL.sln** by running CMake.
3. I opened the solution in Visual Studio 2013 and built it with the Runtime Library setting equal to **/MDd**.
4. I have tried to link the thus compiled library **mysqlclient.lib** to my project(which is compiled with **/MDd**) but I'm still getting the error:

   `mysqlclient.lib(plugin_client.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in main.obj`
5. I have run `dumpbin /all mysqlclient.lib | find /i "mvscr"` obtaining as a result `/DEFAULTLIB:MSVCRTD` which suggests that the library has been compiled as **/MDd**.

I have to admit that before wanting to link mysqlclient.lib to my project I was not even aware of the Runtime Library setting. At this point I don't completely understand why I'm getting the linker error above, which is why I wrote in the title that I think that the library is still getting compiled as **/MTd**. If anyone could point me to the right direction in order to solve my problem it would be very much appreciated.

## EDIT

Reading better the MySQL documentation I found out that if my project is built as /MDd or /MD I have to link it to the libmysql.dll dynamic library. Section **Compiling MySQL Clients on Microsoft Windows**, second to last paragraph.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/c-api-building-clients.html